# "Possible vandalism: deletions" flag should not be triggered by Community auto-deletion

Tags: feature-request, bug, flags, moderator-tools, automatic-flags

Currently, the system will raise a "possible vandalism: deletions" flag when a set number of posts by a user have been deleted in a short period.

This also seems to take into account unvoted answers automatically deleted when questions are cleaned up by the system under the RemoveAbandonedQuestions process. That introduces a significant amount of noise into these flags, because these answers weren't really deleted by the answerer and aren't an indication of someone possibly rage-quitting.

Therefore, I suggest that this automatic flag remove from consideration posts deleted by anyone other than the poster. It should only be triggered by a number of posts deleted in a short period by them. Also, the listing of recently deleted posts provided by the flag should only list these owner-deleted posts.

Comment: Consider adding the [meta-tag:bug] tag.

Comment: But how do we know when Community starts vandalizing the site when Community doesn't flag Community for doing so?